# Is there any restriction on backup-ing sharepoint databases using SQL management studio

Tags: 2013, administration, backup, restore, database

We have SharePoint on-premises farm 2013, and per my knowledge that it is not supported to query the SharePoint databases. but is it a supported operation to select a SharePoint database (for example our manage metadata service database) >> right click on it >> Tasks >> chose to backup >> as follow:-

[image]

or this is not supported?

Answer (score 1):

this is supported method, you are safe to perform the backup this way.

Check this link for more details about the same method.

[Use SQL Server tools to back up a content database in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/back-up-a-content-database#use-sql-server-tools-to-back-up-a-content-database-in-sharepoint-server)